# how can i load persisted data frame in sparkR shell

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

**Context**

I am doing some work in `sparkr` version is `1.5.2`.

- I am loading one csv file in data frame
- and storing that data frame on disk using persist command in `sparkr`.
- now i close that session(`sparkr shell`).
- after one day when i open new `sparkr shell`

**Question**

How i can load that data frame or how i can use that data frame for further operations ?

**Error**

I tried to do with action commands but it is not done. it is giving error

> "object not found".

please help me to find solutions.

Answer (score 3):

`persist` doesn't mean that you are saving the file to disk - it means that you are cacheing it in memory (or memory and disk, for the duration of the session, depending on the storage level you choose - usually you don't persist to MEMORY_AND_DISK - see below). Coming from the R world, caching/persisting is a weird concept, because of course in R, when you read a file, you have it in memory. But not so in SparkR or Spark - if you don't cache/persist the dataframe in memory explicitly, next time you use the dataframe in the same session (e.g. in the next command), it will read the dataframe from file again and everything will be slow. The point of caching is that you have it in memory before operating several times on it, such as before running a machine learning algorithm.

So, to answer your question, if you want to use the same dataframe in a new shell, you have to read the csv file again, or for faster loading, you save the dataframe either as json or parquet format the first time you read from csv file and load as json or parquet the second time (i.e. when you open the new shell).

Note: `cache()` is same as `persist(MEMORY_ONLY)`. You would use `persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)` when:

- you computed dataframe using some other inputs
- the computed dataframe does not fit in memory

If you persist the computed dataframe, the parts that don't fit in memory will be computed and saved to disk and accessed from the disk when they are needed. If you don't persist the computed dataframe, the parts that don't fit in memory will be recomputed on the fly from its original inputs.

To answer your original question, to save a dataframe to disk you would do: 
[see documentation on write.df](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/write.df.html)

```
write.df(df, "myfile", "parquet", "overwrite")
```

and to load you would do: [see documentation on read.df](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/read.df.html)

```
df <- read.df(sqlContext, "path/to/file", source = "parquet")
```